# How do I use XPath to select the text at the end of this element?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

I have elements that look one of two ways. Some like this:

```
<p class="pricing ats-product-price">$3.97</p>
```

And some like this:

```
<p class="pricing ats-product-price"><em class="old_price">$8.97</em>$3.97</p>
```

How can I reliably select the LAST number (`$3.97` in this case) from the element and ignore the first?

The current code I'm using is:

```
$prices = $xpath->query('//p[@class="pricing ats-product-price"]');
```

But in the case of the second style, it will return `$8.973.97`. I just want `$3.97`.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, `$3.97` is in a text node child of the `p` element.

Therefore this XPath,

```
//p[@class="pricing ats-product-price"]/text()
```

will select

```
$3.97
```

in both cases.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I overlooked that. Thank you. Still learning XPath.

Comment: @user393466: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.

Comment: This a very rare case where text() is the right answer! Far more common is for people to use text() when they shouldn't; but your XML structure is unusual.